# Different types of React Routers and their purposes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

On one of my interviews I was asked:

> Name different types of React Routers and their purposes?

I know and use only `react-router-dom` in my projects. It uses to bind DOM elements to specific route in browser without sending request to server.

So, Guy is there other routers types and purpose?

Comment: [Here's a list of some major routers from the React docs](https://reactjs.org/community/routing.html). They're all for presenting components based on location and state (also known as routing). Being able to name any of them doesn't really signal much besides brand awareness

Comment: Depends on what 'React Router' stands for. React Router (with capital R) is package name. It has React Native official adapter besides DOM. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

There are different routers provided by react-router-dom lib:-

1. Browser Router
   A  that uses the HTML5 history API (pushState, replaceState and the popstate event) to keep your UI in sync with the URL.
2. Hash Router
   A  that uses the hash portion of the URL (i.e. window.location.hash) to keep your UI in sync with the URL.
3. Memory Router
   A  that keeps the history of your “URL” in memory (does not read or write to the address bar). Useful in tests and non-browser environments like React Native.

Reference: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter